# Java variables overwriting

Tags: java, overwrite

I have a program with a for that take strings from an Arraylist, split them and sends them to a Worker class.

Worker Class:

```
public class WorkerRSR extends SwingWorker<String, Void>{
private static String urlFrames;
private static String urlImg;
public static int bool;
public static int dist;
public static int numI;
public static int spra;
public static boolean isCoda;
public static int numCoda;
public static String algo;

public WorkerRSR(String urlImg, int dist, int numI, int spra, String algo, String urlFrames, boolean isCoda, int numCoda) {
    this.urlImg=urlImg;
    this.dist=dist;
    this.numI=numI;
    this.spra=spra;
    this.algo=algo;
    this.urlFrames=urlFrames;
    this.isCoda = isCoda;
    this.numCoda = numCoda;

//FIRST CHECK POINT

}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        PanelRSR_LRSR.getProgessbar().setIndeterminate(true);
        go();
        return  "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        System.out.println("Algoritmo RSR esguito");
        if(isCoda){
            CreateOption.codaCont++;
            System.out.println("RSR codaCont: "+CreateOption.codaCont);
            if(CreateOption.codaCont==CreateOption.csize){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Coda Eseguita", "Attenzione",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                PanelRSR_LRSR.getProgessbar().setIndeterminate(false);
            }
        }
        else{
            PanelRSR_LRSR.getProgessbar().setIndeterminate(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Finito RSR", "Attenzione",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public static void go() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("ESEGUO RSR, attendi...");

//SECOND CHECK POINT

        System.out.println("RSR n = "+numI+" codaCont: "+CreateOption.codaCont+" numCoda = "+numCoda);
        while(true){
            if(numCoda==CreateOption.codaCont)
                break;
        }
        MakeRSR m=new MakeRSR();
        String name = urlImg.substring(urlImg.lastIndexOf("\\"),urlImg.lastIndexOf("."));
        String output=name.substring(1); //?
        String urlOutput=urlFrames+"\\finalRSR\\"+name+"-"+algo+"-dist"+dist+"-n"+numI+"-N"+spra+".png";
        m.RSR(urlImg,urlOutput,dist,numI,spra);
    }
}
```

The problem is that this class is going to be called multiple times and every time it overwrite the previous values of the varables: if I check them at the first Checkpoint they are different (probably beacuse the second acquisition yet has to be made), but at the second Checkpoint they are the same.
How can I let them stay different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These variables shouldn't be static if they are set by the constructor. They should be instance variables, so each instance of your class can have different values.

```
public class WorkerRSR extends SwingWorker<String, Void>{
    private String urlFrames;
    private String urlImg;
    private int bool;
    private int dist;
    private int numI;
    private int spra;
    private boolean isCoda;
    private int numCoda;
    private String algo;

    public WorkerRSR(String urlImg, int dist, int numI, int spra, String algo, String urlFrames, boolean isCoda, int numCoda) {
        this.urlImg=urlImg;
        this.dist=dist;
        this.numI=numI;
        this.spra=spra;
        this.algo=algo;
        this.urlFrames=urlFrames;
        this.isCoda = isCoda;
        this.numCoda = numCoda;

//FIRST CHECK POINT

    }

    ...
}
```

You should also change all those variables to be private. If they should be accessed from outside the class, they should be accessed via getter methods.

Comment: also the access modifier is `public`

Comment: First of all, thanks both! :)
As you saw, I'm a newbie and you are really helping me a lot!
I'll take the static away. I don't need to access the variables from outside (this class receives those parameters and then do stuff that's end with an image saving, so there is no get).
@Stephan: What do you mean? Should I change samething to public?

Comment: @pedro He probably meant you should change all the variables to private.

Comment: @pedro i meant that data encapsulation is a good practice , key point being that the attributes can only be modified inside the class.. the public modifier makes them susceptible to external modification

Comment: Like you already did, right?
Anyway, I tried to make the changes you suggested; but, down in the code it asks me to set them static (for example the numI in the output right after the second checkpoin or the numCoda in the do-while).
Did I miss anything?

Comment: @pedro Your `go` method is static, so it can't access instance members of your class. I'm not sure how you intend to use that method. Perhaps it shouldn't be static. If it should be static, it would require an instance of your `WorkerRSR` class in order to access the instance members of it.

Comment: Ok, it looks like it's working!
Thank you both!! You may have not saved my life, but you probably kept me from going mental :D